# PHP REST download file

Tags: php, file, rest

I have a webservice with a function like this

```
$app->get('/downloadPdf', function () use($app) 
{
    $log = 'example.pdf';
    $res = $app->response();
    $res['Content-Description'] = 'File Transfer';
    $res['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream';
    $res['Content-Disposition'] ='attachment; filename=' . basename($log);
    $res['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'binary';
    $res['Expires'] = '0';
    $res['Cache-Control'] = 'must-revalidate';
    $res['Pragma'] = 'public';
    $res['Content-Length'] = filesize($log);
    readfile($log);
});
```

Testing it with Advanced Rest Client works fine..

Question is .. how do i call it from my client with all the headers etc.

To specify more. I know there are a lot of examples on how to download a specific file by inserting its url into the curlopt_url with the complete address to the file. What i want is to let the webservice decide which file to return...

Thanks

Comment: your log file is a php script? `readfile` doesn't execute code, it just streams bytes to output. hopefully it's just a file that happens to have a .php extension on it.

Comment: its just a test file .. i intend to download pdf files with my service ..

Comment: What is your client? javascript on a page? php on a server? ios app? Not sure what you are asking with "how do i call it from my client with all the headers?" The webservice doesn't look like it needs any information... just hit the url /downloadPdf with a get request.

Comment: the request is made from my service handler which is php on the server ..

Comment: im still struggeling with this ... As mentioned i have written the function to handle my request  .. but i still dont understand how to call it from my client code via php... ??? .. help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Never got an answer .. so !!!

This is how i made it work....

Service Function can be seen below

```
$app->post('/downloadReport', 'authenticate', function() use ($app) 
{
verifyRequiredParams(array('reportId'));

$body = $app->request()->getBody();
$params_str = urldecode($body);     
$input = json_decode($params_str,true);             

$report_id = $input['reportId'];    
$db = new DbHandler();    
$db->getReport($report_id);

$path = $db->getReportPdfPath($report_id);

$res = $app->response();
$res['Content-Description'] = 'File Transfer';
$res['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream';
$res['Content-Disposition'] ='attachment; filename=' . basename($path);
$res['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'binary';
$res['Expires'] = '0';
$res['Cache-Control'] = 'must-revalidate';
$res['Pragma'] = 'public';
$res['Content-Length'] = filesize($path);
readfile($path);   

});
```

Called the function like this:

```
public function downloadReport($api_key,$id)
{

    $curl_post_data = array('reportId' => $id);

    $headers = array('Content-type: application/json','Authorization: '.$api_key,);
    $fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/localfile.tmp', 'w+');//This is the file where we save the    information
    $curl = curl_init(DONWLOAD_REPORT);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($curl_post_data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_key);
    $file = curl_exec($curl);

    if ($file === false) 
    {
        $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
    }

    curl_close($curl);

    header('Content-type: ' . 'application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: ' . 'attachment; filename=report.pdf');
    echo $file;        
}
```

Comment: Perfect job thank's!

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem with you, 
I am using this code, and it works, return a pdf file from webservice.

```
        $api = new RestClient(array(
                'base_url' => 'http://another-webservice.com/', 
                'headers' => array(
                                'X-Token'  => $res->headers->x_token,
                                'Accept'  => 'application/pdf',
                             ),
            ));

        $result = $api->execute("reports/report",'GET', $params);

        $filename = 'Report.pdf';
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        echo $result->response;
```

> References: [How to display PDF in Browser](http://yogeshchaugule.com/blog/2013/how-display-pdf-browser-php)