# Download file using wp_remote_post request from API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I'm making an API request to an endpoint that based on the given parameters and details, it'll send back a report in a PDF format for me to view with the details I sent over to it. I'm using WordPress using `wp_remote_post` but having trouble downloading the file to the computer.

This question about [downloading a file in PHP via REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558119/php-rest-download-file) is helpful, but not quite dealing with the same sort of thing/scenario and so I'm stuck on how to get it to work how I need it to.

This is the response I'm getting back using PHP `var_dump`:

```
'date' => string 'Thu, 10 May 2018 11:25:00 GMT' (length=29)
'server' => string 'Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)' (length=21)
'content-disposition' => string 'attachment; filename="xyz.pdf"' (length=37)
'cache-control' => string 'no-cache, private' (length=17)
'x-ratelimit-limit' => string '60' (length=2)
'x-ratelimit-remaining' => string '58' (length=2)
'content-type' => string 'application/pdf' (length=15)
```

In the body part of the response I'm getting this:

```
  'body' => string '%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<<
/Title ( title )
/Creator ( creator )
/Producer ( producer )
/CreationDate ( creationdate )
'... (length=22237)
```

I believe from the response that `wkhtmltopdf` is the library/framework which is creating the PDF that is being sent back. How can I have this file downloaded to the computer as a PDF file to the user that requested it?

I've tried echoing the response and using `urldecode` but I'm not really sure what kind of response this is and how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely just need to set the proper response headers. You can grab the response body with 'wp_remote_retrieve_body', set the headers, and echo the PDF data. Here is an example for you:

```
$data = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="somefile.pdf"');
echo $data;
```

This should cause the file to automatically download.  If you would rather the file be displayed within the browser window then use 'inline' for the Content-Disposition header.

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline');
```

Comment: I've added the code you posted above, but I seem to be getting a `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE` error.

Comment: [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37326576/7236046) helped fix the invalid response, I needed to add the two parameters to the `header` function. But still, thanks as this definitely got me on the right track. Much appreciated.