# How to properly return a .xls Excel file from a UserFrosting controller and process it in Angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, php, angular, userfrosting

I am having problem receiving a Blob of Excel file using Angular 2+'s HttpClient get() method from a UserFrosting API.

Here is the code for the Userfrosting API:

```
public function apiGetAPExport(Request $request, Response $response, $args)
{
        $objPHPExcel = $this->getAPExcelObject($apfilename); // create the PHPExcel Object.

        //  Redirect output to a client's web browser (Excel5)
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$apfilename.'.xls"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

        //  If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

        //  If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
        header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
        header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
        header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
        header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');

        exit;
    }
```

I am using PHP Excel for generating the Excel file.

Here is the Angular functions:

```
btn_createAPfile(){
        const url = this.AppService.fetchHost()+'/api/ap-export';

        let req = this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'blob'})
            .pipe(
                map( // Log the result or error
                    data => {
                        console.log(data);
                        let blob = new Blob([data], { type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"});

                        return blob;
                    },
                    error => console.error("err: ", error)
                )
            );

        req.subscribe(blob => {
            console.log("dbg: ", blob);
            let link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download = "apfile.xls";
            link.click();

            this.populateInvoices();

            setTimeout(function () {
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            }, 0);
        });
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is to download the Excel file using http.get() and when the download is complete, re-populate a table of invoices with `populateInvoices()`. But the problem is, I always get this error on my browser's console when I try to trigger the Angular function:

```
GET http://192.168.33.10/api/ap-export 500 (Internal Server Error)
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.33.10/api/ap-export' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Uncaught HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}
```

I tried to directly input the URL to my browser's address bar and it is working fine.

I know I can do the download with `windows.open()` but I can't repopulate the table with it.

Please help me, what am I missing here?

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558119/php-rest-download-file) for your PHP side and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138424/how-do-i-download-a-file-with-angular2/52588799#52588799) for angular

Comment: @TusharWalzade I appreciate you answering, I tried reading the answrs for those question and experiment with my codes, like changing response header on my API, but nothing seems working.

Answer (score 1):

The error states that 192.168.33.10 has blocked cross origin resource sharing. Your web server isn't allowing a different server or URI to access the API.

Assuming you're using Apache then I've resolved similar issues as follows:

Create an .htaccess file in http://192.168.33.10/api/ containting

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

making sure you have headers mod enabled (linux example below):

```
sudo a2enmod headers
```

I also have in my notes that I needed to allow overrides in the directory the api resides in with in apache2.conf:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Reference and additional information: https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html